# Why is toDataURL() returning blank image? (with p5 video)

Tags: javascript, html, video, p5.js, todataurl

I'm using p5 to display a video with the webcam and send a picture of it when the user clicks a button (along with lat & lon cords). For some reason though, toDataURL() always returns a blank image but I want it to show a snapshot of the video. Here's what I have:

```
function setup() {            
    noCanvas();
    const video = createCapture(VIDEO);
    video.size(320,240);
    video.loadPixels();

    submit.addEventListener('click', async event => {
        position().then(({lat, lon}) => {
            const image = video.canvas.toDataURL();
            data(lat, lon, image);
        })
    })
}
```

submit is the button
data() is the function I'm using to generate a json and send it to the server

I tried to move the .addEventListener() outside of setup() but it did not work

Comment: A runnable [mcve] would make it easier to reproduce the problem and assist here. Thanks.

Comment: @RafiKastner **(1)** Try the second example example [from the docs](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createCapture). As you can see, they do use a canvas so maybe your current code of `noCanvas();` is the mistake. **(2)** To save as image, you either want function [Get()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/get) or [saveCanvas()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/saveCanvas). Try these things and ask a new question about the nearest effort. **PS:** This question was closed as un-answerable because it is currently not testable. Try to write enough code to test (no need for `position()` and `data()` ).